# Li-ion maintenance charging

Tags: batteries, charger, battery-storage

I need to store a small stock of 14500 Li-ion batteries and am looking for an efficient way to maintenance charge them to 40-50% of full capacity. While a timer-based approach is feasible, it will become inaccurate over time and I will need to manually measure the cells, which is bothersome. Are there any chargers with selectable termination voltage? (Voltage is sufficiently accurate capacity indicator for this application). What methods are used by electronics manufacturers handling larger stocks of cells?

Comment: Computerized chargers intended for radio controlled models (cars, drones, planes etc.) usually feature a storage charge mode that brings the battery to 40% - 60% capacity. They don't come with a battery holder for 14500 cells though, so you'd have to make your own. If you check that the cells are at the same voltage beforehand, you could connect several cells in parallel and bring them to a storage charge at the same time.

Comment: Many battery chargers have a storage charge option, which charges the a lithium ion battery to around 3.75V per cell. EV 18650's often come from the factory even lower than that, maybe 3.6V. In practice I've found that batteries can be stored this way for multiple years without damage. Given that, a maintenance circuit would be considered unnecessary by most. Not to mention it adds additional failure modes. When battery packs die quickly on the shelf I believe it's usually due to protection electronics or a "turned off" device applying an excessive quiescent load.

Comment: I have hard time finding a charger with a storage charge option, if you are aware of any models please let me know. Maybe I'm not using the right search terms.